# irrelon/jquery-lang-js does not translate language default

Tags: jquery, translation, lang

Using the irrelon/jquery-lang-js does not translate to english, that is my default language.

I'm using the dynamic translation to apply only the browser language.

It works with spanish and french but when i set the browser language to english it not works

Here is my code:

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
language = language.substr(0, 2);

var lang = new Lang();

lang.dynamic("en", "Languages/lang-en.json");
lang.dynamic("es", "Languages/lang-es.json");
lang.dynamic("fr", "Languages/lang-fr.json");

lang.init({
    defaultLang: "en",
    currentLang: language
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need not declare en as a dynamic language (delete that line), and you should also check the value set for `language` with `console.log(language);`

Try:

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
language = language.substr(0, 2);
console.log(language);
var lang = new Lang();

lang.dynamic("es", "Languages/lang-es.json");
lang.dynamic("fr", "Languages/lang-fr.json");

lang.init({
    defaultLang: "en",
    currentLang: language
});
```

Comment: what does the console.log output for `language`?